# Coming from physically or originate from a place? (Ab Gallia venio)

Tags: meaning, preposition

With "Ab Gallia venio. or "De Gallia venio". (Or other sentences of the same kind)

Could it mean both, I come from this place, or I am originated from this place (like a nationality, or the origin of my family)?

Answer (score 3):

In Classical Latin:

- *ā Galliā veniō* means "I'm coming away/going away from Gaul" or "From Gaul I'm coming to.."
- *dē Galliā veniō* means "I'm arriving from Gaul" or "After/From Gaul I'm coming to.."
- you can also express this more naturally with *dē/ā Gallīs veniō*

The use of *venīre* in the sense you're after doesn't seem to be listed in OLD. Instead you can use:

- *ortū sum Gallus*
- *ortus sum ā/ē Gallīs*
- *oriundus sum (ā/ē) Gallīs* (acc. to Smith&Hall expressing a more remote origin, e.g. of the family's descent)
- *in Galliā nātus sum*
- *ā/dē Gallīs, dē Galliā orīginem dūcō/trahō/habeō*